# DependencyProperty of type ObservableCollection doesn't bind

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection, dependency-properties

I am trying to make a custom control with a `DependencyProperty`.
But I cannot bind my `ObservableCollection` to the control.
When I use an `Enumerable` I have no problem. But I need to add items to the collection so my only option is `ObservableCollection`.

Creating Authorizations:

```
AuthorizationsDest = new ObservableCollection<Authorization>();
        AuthorizationsDest.Add(new Authorization() { Key = "Test1", Description = "Test1", ObjectState = ObjectState.UnModified });
    }
```

The custom control in xaml

```
<customControls:ListBoxEditLookup ItemsSource="{Binding Authorizations}" DisplayMember="Description" DestinationList="{Binding AuthorizationsDest}" />
```

The `DependencyProperty`:

```
[Description("Binded destination list"), Category("Data")]
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("DestinationList", typeof(ObservableCollection<HrdEntity>), typeof(ListBoxEditLookup), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
    public ObservableCollection<HrdEntity> DestinationList
    {
        get
        {
            return GetValue(ItemsProperty) as ObservableCollection<HrdEntity>;
        }
        set { SetValue(ItemsProperty, value); }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'doesn't bind'?  Do you get an error?  Any binding warnings logged?

Comment: Why would you expect this to work? `DestinationList` is of type `ObservableCollection<HrdEntity>`, while `AuthorizationsDest` is of type `ObservableCollection<Authorization>`. In other words, they have two different types that are not assignment-compatible.

Comment: Ok but Authorization is a class that extends from HrdEntity, forget to say that xD

Comment: Because I want to give other collection that also will extend HrdEntity

Comment: @Ghost: That is irrelevant; there are dozens of questions on SO that explain why `GenericClass<Supertype>` and `GenericClass<Subtype>` are different and incompatible, and neither can be assigned to the other. For instance, check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458031/how-to-treat-a-dictionary-of-subclasses-as-a-dictionary-of-the-base-class), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8171549/using-base-class-as-generic-for-ienumerablet), or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15108599/dictionary-compatibility-of-base-class-vs-subclass-values).

Comment: If you just wanna be able to Add and Remove items, use `IList` instead of IEnumerable. But using a generic collection isn't a good idea.

Comment: @almulo: I disagree - using a generic collection is generally an **excellent** idea. You just have to use matching types.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Using generic collections is great, but not for DependencyProperties in potentially reusable controls, specially if we're talking about ObservableCollection<T> and you don't plan on taking advantage of the CollectionChanged event...

Comment: But a binding property like ItemSource can accept all types. How does that work?

Comment: @Ghost: `ItemsSource` in `ItemsControl` is typed `IEnumerable` (which is implemented by almost every collection-related type). The control internally checks whether the enumerable can be cast into a more specialized collection.

Comment: @Ghost Assuming the type in the control is `IEnumerable`, you can check which interfaces it implements and conditionally enable certain features of your control. For example `if (value is INotifyCollectionChanged)` will tell you if you can listen for collection changed events and `if (value is IList)` will tell you if you can index into the collection using the index operator. Typing it specifically as `ObservableCollection<T>` severely limits how it can be used (for example, I use my own `ObservableList<T>` class in my projects because `ObservableCollection<T>` has a very limited API.)

Comment: See e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14837834/1136211) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12746855/1136211) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9128855/1136211) for some code samples.

Comment: What I did is just check if it is of type IList like @Xavier said. (@Xavier if you post it as answer I will accept it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment responses to your question, I think we have arrived at the realization that using a specific concrete collection type on your dependency property is causing issues, and you should consider using an interface such as [IEnumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) instead. Read on for a more detailed explanation.

---

It is generally a good idea to use the [IEnumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) interface as the type for collection dependency properties in a custom control. It is the base interface that every collection implements as it allows `foreach` loops to be run on them. When the dependency property is set, you can inspect the value to see if it implements other interfaces that you care about within your control.

For example, if your control wants to do things like add, remove and insert items and/or index into the collection, check to see if it implements [IList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.aspx). If you want to observe the collection for changes, check to see if it implements [INotifyCollectionChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx).

Consider maintaining private references to the collection that are typed as the interfaces you need to access. For example:

```
private IList mItemsAsList;
private INotifyCollectionChanged mItemsAsObservable;

// Call when the value of ItemsProperty changes
private void OnItemsChanged(IEnumerable newValue)
{
    if (mItemsAsObservable != null)
    {
        mItemsAsObservable.CollectionChanged -= Items_CollectionChanged;
    }

    mItemsAsList = newValue as IList;
    mItemsAsObservable = newValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;

    if (mItemsAsObservable != null)
    {
        mItemsAsObservable.CollectionChanged += Items_CollectionChanged;
    }
}

private void Items_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Do stuff in response to collection being changed
}
```

If there are certain things that are required by your control (not optional), you can always throw an `ArgumentException` in the property changed callback if those requirements are not met. For example, if you must be able to add new items to the collection:

```
mItemsAsList = newValue as IList;
if (newValue != null && (mItemsAsList == null || mItemsAsList.IsReadOnly || mItemsAsList.IsFixedSize))
{
    throw new ArgumentException("The supplied collection must implement IList, not be readonly, and have a variable size.", "newValue");
}
```

Once you have specialized references to the collection, you can limit your functionality based on which interfaces are implemented. For example, let's say you want to add a new item:

```
private void AddItem(object item)
{
    // Make sure to check IsFixedSize because some collections, such as Array,
    // implement IList but throw an exception if you try to call Add on them.
    if (mItemsAsList != null && !mItemsAsList.IsReadOnly && !mItemsAsList.IsFixedSize)
    {
        mItemsAsList.Add(item);
    }
}
```